# Simulate the assembly of parts in Arena Simulation Software

Tags: events, simulation, discrete, arena-simulation

I am simulating an assembly process in Arena. To keep things simple, suppose a model that assigns bags to passengers.

Each entity has a different ID (Entity.SerialNumber): I would like to check which bag has been assigned to which passenger.

How could I write a log file saving the ID of passenger and ID of the assigned bag?

Answer (score 0):

First you must declare an attribute for the original entity that I understand that in this case would be the passenger, for example: ID = ID + 1, then with the separate module you duplicate the original entity, now both entities can have their independent flow and when you want to put them together again you can do it with a batch module using the rule: by attribute or with a match module using the type: based on attribute.